# django sql .raw filtering on a string not working

Tags: python, sql, django, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to filter on a foreign key but getting an error.

Current code is:

views.py

```
def kingmailboxcodesshow(request):
    lname = "King"
    lockbox_list = MailBoxCodes.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM mailboxcodes WHERE Address_id__contains %s',[lname])
    return render(request,"users/mailboxcodesshow.html",{'MailBoxCodes':lockbox_list})
```

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from properties.models import Properties, Building_Name
from django.db.models import Q

# Create your models here.

class MailBoxCodes(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   Address = models.ForeignKey(Properties, max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='Unknown',limit_choices_to=Q(StudentRental=True)| Q(Active=True))
   MailBoxCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False,default='000')
   Active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   class Meta:
      db_table = "mailboxcodes"

   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.Address)
```

receiving this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''King'' at line 1")
```

I am still really new to django and python, looking at the error I am thinking i need a few less ' around the King, but I am not sure how to make that happen.

I have a bunch of addresses in the Address_id and I just want to retrieve all the address with the work King in their street address.

Comment: Don't use raw queries!

Comment: Can you share your `MailBoxCodes` model?

Comment: Will you please try my below answer? Or just try `MailBoxCodes.objects.filter(Address__contains=lname)` see if works for you and can you please also tell in which column does `king` exist to filter with?

Comment: Also share `Properties` model.

Comment: Dear Douglas, have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75282518/17562044) answer?

Answer (score 0):

The great thing with Django is that you don't need raw SQL queries, unless you really really know what you're doing. Please follow the official tutorial as it explains the fundamentals of Django and will guide you through this over here: [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/)

To help you out with this particular issue:

```
def kingmailboxcodesshow(request):
    lname = "King"
    lockbox_list = MailBoxCodes.objects.filter(address__name__contains=lname)
    return render(request,"users/mailboxcodesshow.html",{'MailBoxCodes':lockbox_list})
```

Comment: Thank you! one step forward but I have the following error now: Exception Type:  FieldError
Exception Value: Related Field got invalid lookup: contains - Address_id is a foreign key I don't know if that is the issue.  But THANK YOU FOR THE QUICK RESPONSE Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no such thing as a `__contains` in SQL, that is just some Django logic that transforms it to a query, you can work with:

```
def kingmailboxcodesshow(request):
    lname = 'King'
    lockbox_list = MailBoxCodes.objects.raw(
        'SELECT * FROM mailboxcodes WHERE Address_id LIKE %%%s%%', (lname,)
    )
    return render(
        request, 'users/mailboxcodesshow.html', {'MailBoxCodes': lockbox_list}
    )
```

That being said, using raw queries should be a last resort: the entire idea of Django's ORM is, as you actually found out with this question to make abstraction of query logic. You can run this with:

```
def kingmailboxcodesshow(request):
    lname = 'King'
    lockbox_list = MailBoxCodes.objects.filter(Address_id__contains=lname)
    return render(
        request, 'users/mailboxcodesshow.html', {'MailBoxCodes': lockbox_list}
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! your first example gets one step closer but with the following error: Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable. I am trying to research this now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your `MailBoxCodes` model, and also tell what is this `Address_id` as you mentioned it is a foreign key in one of the comments above.

Try this:

```py
def kingmailboxcodesshow(request):
    lname = 'King'
    lockbox_list = MailBoxCodes.objects.filter(Address__name__contains=lname)
    return render(
        request, 'users/mailboxcodesshow.html', {'MailBoxCodes': lockbox_list}
    )
```

Or this:

```py
MailBoxCodes.objects.filter(Address__contains=lname)
```

You can also use `__icontains` lookup for case-insensitive filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for there assistance. This ended up working perfect.

```
class OneLesterStreetMailBoxCodesListView(ListView):
    queryset = MailBoxCodes.objects.filter( Address__Address1__icontains="251 -")
    context_object_name = '251mailboxcodes'
    template_name = 'mailboxcodes/251_index.html'
```

( Address__Address1__icontains="251 -") <-- Address is the name of the field in MailBoxCodes table, Address1 is the name of the field in the foreign field table.

Hopefully this info will help someone else in the future.